# Backtrack 4 Wireless Not Working

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless, penetration-testing

I'm trying to connect to my wireless network on Backtrack 4. I have a Dell Studio 1558.

ifconfig and ifup show the wlan0 interface is up.

I ran

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
/etc/init.d/wicd
```

in a terminal, but when I open the network manager (menu > internet > wcid network manager), it says that no wireless networks are found.

Is this a driver issue? Does anyone know how to get wireless working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been wireless issues in BT4, either upgrade to BT5 or have a look here in the Backtrack forums as there's loads of information there such as this link on wireless issues in BT5 - http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=43597.

What do you see in /cat var/log/wicd/wicd.log?

What does airmon-ng report?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can go and check the wcid network manager for the name of the wireless device if you have wlan0.
2. Try over terminal with

.

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 up
```